# A script to install OpenVPN & modify iptables?

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, openvpn

I d like to automatize the install/config of OpenVPN on my client machines.
Roughly, it should looks like :
- apt-get openvpn
- cp, edit, ....
- modify iptables.

Is it possible in one script ? or am I a bit naive ?

__ EDIT __
My way for now :

```
# 1. install openvpn :
$ sudo apt-get install openvpn
# 2. request client config ( I did a php+shell script for)  (=> config.ovpn, key, crt + !! ca.crt )
# 3. connexion
$ sudo openvpn MaConfig.ovpn
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look at tools like Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, etc...

Comment: @jasonwryan I ll look at, thks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the server decide over the client machines place in the network. Check `--client-config-dir` in the manual `openvpn(1)`. The configuration is selected by the CN Field of the client certificate.
2. Tuning iptables can be done in some `--up`, `--down`, `--ipchange`, `--iproute` command, that is configured in your client configuration.

So basically your script has to

- install openvpn,
- setup the client configuration,
- setup the client certificate and key and the server certificate for SSL-VPN,
- setup some scripts to change your iptables when the interface or the route comes up